# Make virtual path in Term Store Management Tool

Tags: 2013, term

Is it possible in the Term Store Management Tool (SharePoint 2013) when you only have editor rights to make a " virtual path " to a page, from which you redirect to a page that is location a other place?

In other words, on my website, I have surmised that many have bookmarked a url `/bog/krimi/pages/ole.aspx`.

The page is now moved to `/krimibog/olehansen` and the users that enter the old url `/bog/krimi/pages/ole.aspx` gets an error page. Therefore they need to be redirected to the new location.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you create a page in this url `/bog/krimi/pages/ole.aspx` and add a content editor web part which redirect the user to the actual page.

Inside the content editor use below code

```
<script>
window.location = '/krimibog/olehansen'
</script>
```

Comment: Many thanks for your reply.
I do not think this is the correct solution, when I first need to build the old structure up again. Is it not possible to place a term outside the structure and redirected to a page??